# Windows crashed, *.tex file empty, but I can select empty lines

Tags: compiling, texmaker

I'm in big trouble... My windows crashed when I was compiling a tex file and after restart I can see that the file is 19 kb and it has something in it, but I can't read it. I can even copy the empty lines. Did any of you encounter this? And no, I didn't do any backup to that specific file. I am using \input{thefile.tex} and I don't know how to back it up... Anyone... help?

And any help on how to back-up files that are not defined as main would be highly appreciated!

Edit: Now I get !

Text line contains an invalid character.

Paul

Comment: If the problem is a corrupted source code seem a little off-topic here. BTW, then main and child files are both simple plain text files. You can copy  these files as any other file in your hard disk. My guess is that may be is only a problem with the editor program. Try to open those files with different text editors, but do not  overwrite any file. If no program can open correctly some file, you will need a recovery tool as `testdisk` and hope the best.

Comment: In terms of backing up files that aren't your main one, I would have thought simply copying over `thefile.tex` to an external hard drive or similar would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you guys. This is so weird... I couldn't save it, unfortunately, but I started writing over again and I have a lot of text there, but I can't compile nor copy/paste the text inside. It's like I am writing in a black hole... I tried with different editors and nothing.

Comment: The first rule of file recovery is to make a back up before you lose stuff. The second is not to touch the disk from which you want to recover data from one or more files. Work only on a copy of the disk. However, you have presumably given up on recovering the data. In which case, just start a new file and destroy this one.

Comment: Does Windows check the integrity of the file system when recovering from a crash? Was it able to fix any problems it found? (This is off-topic.)

Comment: @cfr, is there any way I can do that automatically in TeXMaker? Or write a tex code for that?

Comment: Do what? The file system should be checked when booting after a crash before the file system is mounted. At least, unless Windows does something totally different, which seems unlikely in this case. You can check file systems which are mounted, but you can't generally correct any problems, so this is usually done as part of the boot sequence. I'm pretty sure Windows does it when `not properly shut down` unless you explicitly skip it. It has nothing to do with TeX.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry. I forgot the word "backup". Let me rephrase the question. Is there any way to make TeXMaker do automatic backup to the *.tex files that I import using \input{file.tex}?

Comment: And just a heads-up... I lost everything. I had the PDF that was generated right before the crash and I could copy/paste text. Putting back the figures was a bit more challenging.